# What is the behavior of allies' spells and items' actives on stealth?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to know what happens when Orianna uses her shield (E) on Khazix and he uses his stealth (R). Does the ball disappear too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** The ball effectively disappears. By this mean you can create some really scary shockwaves like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eluDcIJ_Qo) !

[Zilean bombs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJXKUXax17U) can be pretty surprising too.

More generally, any animation relative to an external allied champion on a stealthed champion will be invisible (Taric and Kalista bonds, Shen R, etc).

---

**EDIT :** However, **items actives** often remove stealth.

*Examples*:

- Zhonya's Hourglass
- Talisman of Ascension
- Hextech GLP-800
- Hextech Protobelt-01
- Hextech Gunblade
- Redemption
- Randuin's Omen
- Righteous Glory
- Blade of the Ruined King
- Bilgewater Cutlass

*Exceptions*:

- Youmuu's Ghostblade
- Preparing Veil
- Quicksilver Sash
- Mercurial Scimitar

Comment: Are there any exceptions?
What about Sona abilities or item actives on stealthed champions?

Comment: Precise items actives ? Something like Youmuu's Ghostblade's active won't be seen for eample.

Comment: I meant stuff like Relic Shield category of items - Spoils of War passive or even Talisman of Ascension active.

Comment: Are you sure warding removes stealth? Because warding doesn't even cancel your recall.

Comment: BTW: Whichever item attatches does disappear, however the effect does not. That means a teammate can effectively give your location by using items on you.

Comment: @Kruga I'll check asap. I'll put it back if it does remove stealth.

Comment: Ohmwrecker probably does, too. Don't feel like you have to post an exhaustive list, though. One can't use Ohmwrecker near a tower and not be revealed by the tower's true sight, for example.